# Gstreamer pipeline grammar

Tags: gstreamer

I am using gstreamer pipeline to encode a mp4 file to different bitrate. I constructed the pipeline using the code from gst-streaming-server. The pipeline does not seem to work. I am not able to understand the pipeline syntax here to debug it.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=video_test.mp4 name=src ! \
  decodebin name=dec queue name=vqueue ! \
  videosegmentclip name=vclip ! \
  videoconvert ! \
  video/x-raw, format=I420 ! \
  videocrop top=0 bottom=0 left=0 right=0 ! \
  queue ! \
  tee name=vtee queue name=aqueue max-size-time=5000000000 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-     buffers=0 ! \
  audiosegmentclip name=aclip ! \
  audioconvert ! \
  audio/x-raw, channels=2 ! \
  audioresample ! \
  audio/x-raw, rate=48000 ! \
  voaacenc bitrate=128000 ! \
  queue ! \
  tee name=atee vtee. ! \
  queue ! \
  videoscale add-borders=false ! \
  video/x-raw,pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1,width=1280,height=720 ! \
  x264enc name=venc0 bitrate=2372 tune=zerolatency ! \
  queue ! \
  mp4mux name=mux0 ! \
  watchdog timeout=5000 ! \
  filesink name=sink0 location=out0.mp4  atee. ! \
  queue ! \
  mux0. \
```

Above is the full pipeline. The tough part for me is in understanding are below

```
decodebin name=dec queue name=vqueue
```

There is no ! in the line above and should there not be a ! between decodebin and queue

```
tee name=vtee queue name=aqueue... ! audiosegmentclip
```

In the above line there is a tee which is named vtee (videotee) but linked to audiosegmentclip. How does this work?

```
tee name=atee vtee. ! queue
```

In the above line there is a tee named atee immediately followed by vtee. What is the meaning of this? what is the significance of having a period(.) after the element?

Any links explaining the gstreamer pipeline grammer would be very helpful.

Comment: you need to link the bin to the queue `decodebin name=dec ! queue name=vqueue` and the tee `tee name=vtee ! queue name=aqueue...`

Comment: That is giving me a different error GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:616:gst_parse_perform_link: could not link aqueue to aclip

Comment: which makes sense because you are trying to send video clips to it...

Comment: Thanks Trent. I am a novice with gstreamer. My objective is to split the audio and video streams then encode it with specific bitrates and then mux it. How can I modify this pipeline to that end.

Comment: so, read from a file, move audio and video to a specific bit rate and then mux them together again right?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want with condition that the output has to be MPEG-TS format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general idea that you want can be found in this pipeline. The main differences of which are:

1. There is no need for a Tee as the `decodebin` has numerous sink pads to link against different media types
2. I handle the video logically first, push it to the mux, and then the audio. I find that mixing the audio and video elements together in a pipeline screws me up logically and it is easier to handle one first and then the other.
3. I removed some items that you could probably add back if you really wanted to(some queue settings and filters)

   `gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.mp4 name=src ! decodebin name=dec ! \
      queue name=vqueue ! videosegmentclip name=vclip ! videoconvert ! \
      video/x-raw, format=I420 ! videocrop top=0 bottom=0 left=0 right=0 ! \
      videoscale add-borders=false ! \
      video/x-raw,pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1,width=1280,height=720 ! \
      x264enc name=venc0 bitrate=2372 tune=zerolatency ! queue ! mux. dec. ! \
      audiosegmentclip name=aclip ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw, channels=2 ! \
      audioresample ! audio/x-raw, rate=48000 ! voaacenc bitrate=128000 ! \ 
      queue ! mp4mux name=mux ! watchdog timeout=5000 ! \
      filesink name=sink0 location=out0.mp4`

Comment: Thanks Trent. The pipeline is working. How could I make it work by using mpegtsmux element in place of mp4mux as I need a MPEG-TS stream. I could do with mp4, but when I segment a mp4 file using (key-int-max attribute on x264enc) my segments are not playable. But when I segment on MPEG-TS file the files are playable.

Comment: you probably could just swap out the elements and add the needed attributes without issue. I don't believe there would be any failed cap negotiations

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with the syntax too. The gst-launch-1.0 man page says:

> A  pipeline  consists  elements and links. Elements can be put into
>   bins of different sorts. Elements, links and bins can be specified in
>   a pipeline
>          description in any order.

I got confused by thinking that ! (a link) is like a bash pipe and that elements are like bash commands that generate and receive data, and thus you had to have a list of commands joined with !. In gstreamer, that is not the case. The pipeline description is a list of elements, links, and bins in any order. Here's my attempt at a grammar (leaving out bins and caps). Note that `*` means variable number of and `/` means one of the alternatives.

```
pipeline = pipeline_item*
pipeline_item = element / link
element = NAME property*
property = NAME=VALUE
link = ! / pad ! pad
pad = ELEMENT_NAME. / ELEMENT_NAME.padnames
padnames = NAME / NAME,padnames
```

Or, to summarize in English:

- NAME is a element
- NAME=VALUE is a property
- NAME. or NAME.PAD is a pad (note the . after both forms)
- ! is a link and can be used like:

  - element1 ! element2
  - element1 name=e1 element2 name=e2 e1. ! e2.
  - element1 name=e1 element2 name=e2 e1.src ! e2.sink